# Using a R Script on multiple folders

Tags: r

I would like to use a R Script that i wrote on Multiple Folders that include a csv file and a text file.
The function i wrote takes the csv and the text file and calculates a vector.

So basically the code i need would open every folder, take the csv file and the text file and would calculate me the fitting vectors.

I thought about using list.files to get a list with the names of all folders and then use lapply to apply the function on every folder, but i dont know how to define the read.csv and read.table.

```
    setwd("C:\\WD")
ptf = "C:\\PathtoFiles"
temp = list.files(path = ptf)
lapply(temp, exfunction)


exfunction = function() {
  csvfile = read.csv("nameofile.csv")
  textfile = read.table("nameoffile.txt", header=TRUE)
  calcvec = vector(mode = "numeric", length = length(textfile))
  #Code that calculates the vector
  return(calcvec)
}
```

Comment: You should replace your function with a variable. As you're calling the same file over and over again. exfunction = function(x) {
  csvfile = read.csv(x)
  textfile = read.table(x, header=TRUE)
  calcvec = vector(mode = "numeric", length = length(textfile))
  #Code that calculates the vector
  return(calcvec)
}

Comment: But then the problem still remains how the function would know the arguments.